# Multipanels using Manipulate and variable dependence

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to change the values of the variables in `Manipulate`? Suppose I have a `Manipulate` with two variables, `x` and `y` and we display the values. What I want to do is to make it in such a way that when I change the value of `x`, `y` gets updated to `x`*`x`. When I change the value of `y`, then `x` gets updated to the square root of `y`.

The other question is, can I have multiple panels in `Manipulate`? I would like to have a white panel under each slider.

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{x, y}, "    "],
 Row[{
   Control[{{x, 0, Style["x", "TI", 14]}, 0, 4 , Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
   Control[{{y, 0, Style["y", "TI", 14]}, 0, 16, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
 }]
]
```

[image: Example]

In the above plot I have set `x` to 3 and `y` to 9. Again, I would like to move `y` to say 4 and have `x` to move to `2`. Similarly, I want to move `x` to 4 and have `y` move to 16.
Is is possible? or have I just encountered the chicken or the egg problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit hack-ish but to couple the sliders and get two panels, you could also do something like this

```
Panel[DynamicModule[{x, y, width = 250},
  Grid[{{
     Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; y = #^2) &], {0, 5}],
      {Style["x", "TI", 14], Dynamic[x]}, {Left, Right}],
     Labeled[Slider[Dynamic[y, (y = #; x = Sqrt[#]) &], {0, 25}],
      {Style["y", "TI", 14], Dynamic[y]}, {Left, Right}]},

    Framed[Pane[#, width, Alignment -> Center], FrameMargins -> 10,
       Background -> White, FrameStyle -> {Gray}] & /@ 
     {Row[{"x=", Dynamic[x]}], Row[{"y=", Dynamic[y]}]}}, Alignment -> Left]]]
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Double panel]

Comment: Very nice. This is a very good answer. Just one more question. Do you know how Manipulate creates its sliders? I was reading the documentation about DynamicModule and in one example it says: "Manipulate relies on DynamicModule to create the output" and it shows a Manipulate with one slider. This however doesn't show how I can get the slider with the plus sign to get the InputField and other controls. Do you know how to add this?

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0},
  {Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 1}],
  Slider[Dynamic[x^2, (x = Sqrt@#) &], {0, 1}]}]
```

[image]

which is a trivial modification of a code snippet I found in `tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic` in the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html)?

EDIT: You can add panels etc as follows:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0},
  Row[{Column[{Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 1}], Panel@Dynamic@x}],
  Column[{Slider[Dynamic[x^2, (x = Sqrt@#) &], {0, 1}],
    Panel@Dynamic@Sqrt[x]}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to have each question separate. Hard to answer 2 questions in same place.

For the first question, you can use your own Dynamics to obtain better control. Here is one way:

```
Manipulate[
  Row[{
      Dynamic[Refresh[Text@Row[{"x=",x," y=",y}],TrackedSymbols->{event}]],
      Dynamic[Refresh[event=Date[];y=x*x;"",TrackedSymbols->{x}]],
      Dynamic[Refresh[event=Date[];x=Sqrt[y];"",TrackedSymbols->{y}]]
     }],
  {{x,2,"x"},0,100,1},
  {{y,2,"y"},0,1000,1},
  {{event,0},ControlType->None},
  TrackedSymbols:>{None}
]
```

[image]

For your second question, a Manipulate, has one 'panel'  where output goes to. So, you can't really do it with one Manipulate. But you can nest Manipulates, so you can do it that way by having each manipulate with its own controls all under one Manipulate.

### Update1:

To share variables between 2 inner Manipulate, so when one Manipulate update its own variable, the other Manipulate sees the latest update, here is one possible way. When you movbe one Manipulate slider, the second Manipulate updates automatically with the new value.

```
Manipulate[

   Grid[{{

    Manipulate[( gx=x; Row[{"x=",x," y=",gy}]),
               {{x,1,"x="},0,10,1}],
    Manipulate[( gy=y; Row[{"x=",gx," y=",y}]),
               {{y,1,"y="},0,10,1}]
   }}],

{{gx,0},ControlType->None},
{{gy,0},ControlType->None},

ControlPlacement->Bottom
]
```

[image]

Comment: How will I get my variables to communiate in the case I have one big manipulate with 2 submanipulates?

Comment: not sure if there is a better way, but you could simply use the outer Manipulate as means to pass updates from Manipulate to the other by setting an upper controls of type None. See Update 1 for my answer for an example.